# "Error' format exception when post second data from flutter to MySQL using API Laravel"

Tags: json, laravel, flutter, api, rest

When the first time I debug my program and post data to API, it works, but when I try to open another form data using the same API, I got an Error Format Exception. If I re-debug and open the form data again using the same API, it works. I try to use POSTMAN to spam POST to API to see if my API got trouble or not, the result is it's working, my API can get spam POST data. So I guess the problem is with my flutter code. Can someone help me? Thank you Very Much

My List Data Page.dart (to access form data):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/colors.dart';
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/murid/detail_sesi_murid.dart';
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/murid/report_guru.dart';
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/murid/review_guru.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class history_sesi_murid extends StatefulWidget {
  int? index_user;
  history_sesi_murid({super.key, required this.index_user});

  @override
  State<history_sesi_murid> createState() =>
      _history_sesi_muridState(index_user);
}

class _history_sesi_muridState extends State<history_sesi_murid> {
  int? index_user;
  _history_sesi_muridState(this.index_user);
  void initState() {
    print(index_user);
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future getdatatransesi() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/transaksi_sesi/murid/" +
            index_user.toString()));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Skripsi c14190201",
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: containerColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: appbarColor,
          title: Text(
            "History Sesi",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          toolbarHeight: 75,
          // leadingWidth: 65,
          // titleSpacing: 0,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 30, 5, 30),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: getdatatransesi(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text(
                      "Total Sesi : " +
                          (snapshot.data['data'].length - 1).toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: "Roboto",
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text("data error");
                  }
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: getdatatransesi(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data['data'].length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (snapshot.data['data'][index]['id_sesi'] != 0) {
                            return Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data['data'][index]['id_transaksi'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return review_guru(data_transaksi: snapshot.data['data'][index]);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: buttoncolor,
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Review",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return report_guru(data_transaksi: snapshot.data['data'][index]);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: buttoncolor,
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Report",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return detail_sesi_murid(
                                            index_user: index_user,
                                            index_sesi: snapshot.data['data']
                                                [index]['id_sesi'],
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    primary: buttoncolor,
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Detail",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          } else {
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text("data error");
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My form data page.dart (Use to POST data from dart to MySQL):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/colors.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/murid/detail_guru.dart';
import 'package:skripsi_c14190201/murid/history_sesi_murid.dart';

class review_guru extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map data_transaksi;
  review_guru({super.key, required this.data_transaksi});

  @override
  State<review_guru> createState() => _review_guruState(data_transaksi);
}

class _review_guruState extends State<review_guru> {
  final Map data_transaksi;
  _review_guruState(this.data_transaksi);

  void initState() {
    print(data_transaksi);
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    penilaianmuridController.dispose();
    komentarmuridController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  TextEditingController penilaianmuridController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController komentarmuridController = TextEditingController();

  String mataPelajaran = "";
  Future getdatasesi() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/sesi/" +
        data_transaksi['id_sesi'].toString()));
    var response2 = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/user_guru/" +
            data_transaksi['id_guru'].toString()));
    mataPelajaran =
        json.decode(response2.body)['data']['mata_pelajaran'].toString();
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  Future savedata() async {
    final response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/review"), body: {
      "id_sesi": data_transaksi['id_sesi'].toString(),
      "id_murid": data_transaksi['id_murid'].toString(),
      "id_guru": data_transaksi['id_guru'].toString(),
      "penilaian_sesi": penilaianmuridController.text,
      "komentar_sesi": komentarmuridController.text,
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body)['message'];
    } else {
      return json.decode(response.body)['message'];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Skripsi c14190201",
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: containerColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: appbarColor,
          title: Text(
            "Review",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          toolbarHeight: 75,
          // leadingWidth: 65,
          // titleSpacing: 0,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Scrollbar(
          trackVisibility: true,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 30, 20, 30),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder(
                    future: getdatasesi(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "ID Sesi : " +
                                  snapshot.data['data']['id'].toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              mataPelajaran,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                fontSize: 13,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data['data']['tanggal_sesi'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  " | ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data['data']['waktu_sesi'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "ID Guru : " +
                                  snapshot.data['data']['id_guru'].toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                                fontSize: 13,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Text("data error");
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      TextField(
                        controller: penilaianmuridController,
                        autofocus: true,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                        ],
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          label: Text(
                            "Penilaian (0 - 10)",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        controller: komentarmuridController,
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          label: Text(
                            "Komentar",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Roboto",
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          save_review();
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: buttoncolor,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Submit",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Roboto",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future save_review() async {
    if (penilaianmuridController.text.isEmpty ||
        komentarmuridController.text.isEmpty) {
      Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "Data belum lengkap",
        type: AlertType.error,
        buttons: [],
      ).show();
    } else {
      savedata().then((value) {
        print(value);
        if (value == "success") {
          Alert(
            context: context,
            title: "Data Review Berhasil Ditambahkan",
            type: AlertType.success,
            buttons: [],
          ).show();
        } else {
          Alert(
            context: context,
            title: value,
            type: AlertType.error,
            buttons: [],
          ).show();
        }
      });
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return detail_guru(
              index_user: data_transaksi['id_murid'],
              index_guru: data_transaksi['id_guru'],
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

My Controller file from laravel (to Get data form flutter and POST it into MySql):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\review;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class API_ReviewMuridController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $review = review::all();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'success', 'data' => $review]);
    }
    public function show($id){
        $review = review::find($id);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'success', 'data' => $review]);
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        // SELECT * FROM `reviews` INNER JOIN sesis ON reviews.id_sesi = sesis.id;
        $cek_review = review::where('id_sesi', $request->id_sesi)->get();
        if($cek_review->isEmpty()){
            $review = new review();
            $review->id_sesi = $request->id_sesi;
            $review->id_murid = $request->id_murid;
            $review->id_guru = $request->id_guru;
            $review->penilaian_sesi = $request->penilaian_sesi;
            $review->komentar_sesi = $request->komentar_sesi;
            $review->save();
            return response()->json(['message' => 'success', 'data' => $review]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Data Review Sudah Ada.', 'data' => $cek_review]);
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Tolong dicoba lagi.', 'data' => $cek_review]);
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id){

    }
    public function destroy($id){
        $review = review::find($id);
        $review->delete();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'success', 'data' => null]);
    }
}
```

The Error when I try to open form data.dart for the second time:

[image: The Error when i try to open form data.dart for the second time]

I try to POST data as many times as I want without getting a break/have to re-debug before POST the second data.